# Can't send e-mail from new domain on exchange 2010

Tags: domain, exchange-2010, outlook-2010

Masters,

We have a new domain which added on Organisation --> Hub transport --> Accepted domain. New mail policy also created, so my new myname@newdomain.com e-mail adress generated as well.

Because this is for testing purposes for a while, i did'n set this new e-mail as primpary.

When write a new e-mail in outlook i type my new address as sender and try to send a test mail but get message:

```
 You can not send a message to the user on his behalf, unless it has permission to do so. Make sure you give the correct name of the sender, or ask the necessary authorization. If the problem persists, contact Support.
```

I have admin rights, this is my e-mail.

Need help what i missed and what else may i set in exhchange.

Thank you Masters

Comment: *Because this is for testing purposes for a while, i did'n set this new e-mail as primpary.* -  Is it the primary and you still get this error?

Comment: Unless this is your primary email address, you would encounter an error if you apply an alternative email address in the "FROM" field

Comment: may i send some test somehow?

Comment: I changed my primary e-mail address to new one. From OWA i can send mail, but it seems Outlook client not affected. It seem the old e-mail keepd. May i need something to change on client side?

Comment: I don't understand what there is to test. Set the new email address as your primary SMTP address and be done with it. You can do this en masse by editing the E-Mail address Policy or for just your mailbox by unchecking the `Automatically update e-mail addresses based on e-mail address policy` checkbox on the E-Mail Addresses tab of your recipient object and setting the new email address as your Reply Address.

Answer (score 0):

So..as Lex is commented above we need to set the new address as primary address...

If we set this, we can send e-mail from new address but in outlook the from field seems stuck with the old address....

If you want to change this (its just a text..new e-mail send from new address) you have to create new profile....